# Could not extract result in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I can't extract result in hibernate.. I want to check an account when they sign in but it throws an exception: could not extract result.

My sample code:

My Pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class TestAccount implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="IDACCOUNT")
    private Integer idAccount;

    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="ISDELETED")
    private Integer isDeleted;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ROLE")
    private TestAccountRole accountRole;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="accountInfo", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private TestAccountInfo accountInfo;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_role")
public class TestAccountRole implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="IDACCOUNT_ROLE")
    private Integer idAccountRole;

    @Column(name="ROLE")
    private String role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="accountRole", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<TestAccount> accounts = new HashSet<TestAccount>(0);
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class TestAccountInfo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="IDACCOUNT_INFO")
    private Integer idAccountInfo;

    @Column(name = "BIRTHDAY")
    private String birthday;

    @Column(name = "SEX")
    private String sex;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "ISDELETED")
    private Integer isDeleted;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private TestAccount accountInfo;
}
```

My Dao:

```
public TestAccount Authenticate(String username, String password) {

    String passMD5 = AccountUtil.md5(password);
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String sql = "from Account where username = ? and password = ?";
    Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
    query.setString(0, username);
    query.setString(1, passMD5);
    //query.setInteger(2, 0);
    TestAccount account = (TestAccount) query.uniqueResult();
    if (account != null) {
      return account;
    }
    return null;
}
```

My Db:

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `IDACCOUNT` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USERNAME` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ISDELETED` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ROLE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDACCOUNT`),
  KEY `ROLEACCOUNT_idx` (`ROLE`),
  CONSTRAINT `ROLEACCOUNT` FOREIGN KEY (`ROLE`) REFERENCES `account_role` (`IDACCOUNT_ROLE`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE `account_info` (
  `IDACCOUNT_INFO` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BIRTHDAY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEX` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDRESS` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PHONE` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ISDELETED` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDACCOUNT_INFO`),
  CONSTRAINT `ACCOUNTINFO` FOREIGN KEY (`IDACCOUNT_INFO`) REFERENCES `account` (`IDACCOUNT`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE `account_role` (
  `IDACCOUNT_ROLE` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ROLE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDACCOUNT_ROLE`)
)
```

An exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)


root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'account0_.IDACCOUNTROLE' in 'field list'
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
String sql = "from TestAccount where username = ? and password = ?";
```

Comment: @ThanhDuyNgo what exception

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'account0_.IDACCOUNTROLE' in 'field list'

Comment: @ThanhDuyNgo Can you give the exact line number from where the exception coming

Comment: when I debug, they throw an exception when I try to do this line:
TestAccount account = (TestAccount) query.uniqueResult();

Comment: @ThanhDuyNgo make `@Column(name="IDACCOUNTROLE")` instead of `@Column(name="IDACCOUNT_ROLE")`

Comment: @ThanhDuyNgo is it working ?.it is better if you use only `@Column` and let the hibernate do the naming

Comment: @ThanhDuyNgo Also you have to recreate the whole databse

Comment: I found my mistake.. I change  the column name Role in DB and it works :)

Comment: @ThanhDuyNgo I have told you the same thing `@Column(name="IDACCOUNTROLE")` is for changing the column name

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class TestAccountInfo implements Serializable {
```

Table name is incorrect in TestAccountInfo. It should be corrected as 
      @Table(name = "account_info")

Query also need to change

```
String sql = "from TestAccount where username = ? and password = ?";
```

Comment: Did u change the query as well?

Comment: I've already changed the query like you but it still doesnt work

Comment: @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ROLE")
    private TestAccountRole accountRole;                                 change join column name to IDACCOUNT_ROLE instead of ROLE